# nextUntil() jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

why does it return an error?

http://jsfiddle.net/L82JU/

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'replace'

I want to select the first child of `.x` until the 3rd child of `.x`

html

```
<div class="x">
    <div class="a">a</div>
    <div class="b">b</div>
    <div class="c">c</div>
    <div class="d">d</div>
    <div class="e">e</div>
</div>
```

jquery

```
a=$('.x').children();
alert(a.eq(0).nextUntil(a.eq(3)).length);
```

Comment: browser specific? there is no error in Chrome

Comment: @Anwar Chandra: It's possible that Chrome gives you a different string value for an object, something that doesn't cause a parsing error in jQuery, but it still won't give you something that can be used as a selector, so it won't work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.nextUntil` expects a string, not an object. In your example, you're passing an object, which has no `replace` method. You need to pass the selector.

You could try this instead:

```
alert(a.eq(0).nextUntil('.d').length);
```

Or if you don't know the specific selector ahead of time:

```
alert(a.eq(0).nextAll().slice(2).length);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L82JU/5/

Answer (score 3):

[`.nextUntil()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) takes a selector not an object.  Try:

```
alert( a.eq(0).nextUntil( '.' + a.eq(3).attr('class') ).length );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L82JU/3/

Answer (score 1):

The `nextUntil` method takes a selector, not an element.

Also, you should not use `eq(0)` before `nextUntil`, that will reduce the collection to the first element, and you can't loop to the third element in a collection with only one element.

http://jsfiddle.net/L82JU/4/

```
a=$('.x').children();
alert(a.nextUntil('.c').length);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would rather write it like this, it's faster and shorter:

```
$('.x').children(':lt(4)');
```

This selects all the children of '.x' that is less than 4 (1-3).